# XMPPFramework and Openfire sever, authentication successful ,but not call back

Tags: objective-c, openfire, xmppframework

Connect opefire server ok , and then to authentication:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender{
    NSLog(@"connected --->YES");
    isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:@"password" error:&error];
}
```

Openfire logs show:

```
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Launching thread for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Launching thread for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Launching thread for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - 000065 (01/05/00) - Connection #5 tested: OK
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - 000066 (01/05/00) - Connection #5 tested: OK
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthorizationManager - AuthorizationManager: Trying Default Mapping.map(shitiven)
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthorizationMapping - DefaultAuthorizationMapping: No realm found
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthorizationManager - AuthorizationManager: Trying Default Policy.authorize(shitiven , shitiven)
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthorizationPolicy - DefaultAuthorizationPolicy: Checking authenID realm
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - 000066 (01/05/00) - Connection #2 tested: OK
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - 000067 (01/05/00) - Connection #2 tested: OK
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - 000067 (01/05/00) - Connection #1 tested: OK
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - 000068 (01/05/00) - Connection #1 tested: OK
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Launching thread for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Launching thread for /121.0.29.220:60789
2012.08.01 19:13:35 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for /121.0.29.220:60789
```

But the delegate method "xmppStreamDidAuthenticate" not call:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender{
     NSLog(@"login success!!"); 
     [self goOnline];
}
```

When I type wrong userid or password , the delegate method "didNotAuthenticate" call:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error{
    NSLog(@"authenticate fail %@",error); //console to the debug pannel
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're being haunted by the issue described here: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/81

You will have to update xmppframework to fix this.